# replace characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, nsstring

I would like to wipe a NSString object in my code (replace every characters by 0).

To do that I tried this :

```
NSString *myString;
for (int i=0; i<[myString length]; i++) 
{
myString[i] = 0;
}
```

But it doesn't compile : "Incompatible types in assignment" at line *myString[i] = 0;*

I understand, but I can't use function *stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString* because it creates a new object and I would like to replace characters in my first object.

Any help ?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to achieve because what you are doing is a little strange, 0 is not really a valid character in most string encodings, it is used to terminate the string, though how NSString does this is its business. Unless you mean '0' character. Perhaps you may want to use a char array to build your string and then when you are finished create a NSString from that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSString` is immutable, meaning that you can not change its contents once its created. You have [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that purpose.

Also, you can not access the characters in a `NSString` or `NSMutableString` with this syntax:

```
myString[i] = 0;
```

`NSString`s and `NSMutableString`s are objects and you work with objects by sending messages to them. For instance, you have `characterAtIndex:` method that returns the character at the given index, or `NSMutableString`'s `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` that replaces all occurrences of a given string in a given range with another given string.

Comment: also, also: myString[i] returns type unichar, and 0 is of integral type, which probably explains the unhelpful compiler error

Comment: Nice detailed explanation. +1

Comment: @albertamg Thanks for your answer. I will use NSMutableString.

Answer (score 2):

By Definition, NSString is an immutable class, so the data inside of it is unchangeable.

You are looking for the [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableString) class, which implements the following method:

```
replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
```

Which you can use to replace characters or substrings within the object you send that message to.